# overlap owl carousel with another div

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm trying to display a div with `position: absolute;` on `:hover` in css. Beneath the button displaying the hidden div there is an owl carousel with semi-transparent images inside. The menu inside the div is being displayed behind the carousel. I tried using a higher z-index for the div, but this doesn't solve the issue. Is there a css method that can force display of the div above another item? The code can be found [here](http://www.loreleywines.be/index2.php#FAVORIETEN).

[image]

The css code for the div:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 999 !important;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: You're looking for `z-index` to have an item display on top of another item. You'll need a value of at least `1000`, as your dropdown has a value of `999`.

Comment: The dropdown is the one I want to have on top, hence the z-index of 999.

Comment: The css of the owl-carousel is rather complex, I tried to adjust numerous values here, but no succes

Comment: Well it's certainly the `z-index` property that you want to play around with. Maybe manually assign a low `z-index` to the element you want to be underneath. Keep in mind that `z-index` only works on positioned elements. You need to manually specify a fixed, relative or absolute position for anything with a `z-index`.

Comment: the dropdown-content is positioned absolute, the owl-carousel relative and has a z-index of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will fix your issue:

```
.wine_filters {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```